# Oracle SQL: Get the previous values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns table: Id, and value.

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | AA |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | BB |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 | CC |
| 9 |  |

I need a query in Oracle to return the result as

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | AA |
| 3 | AA |
| 4 | BB |
| 5 | BB |
| 6 | BB |
| 7 | BB |
| 8 | CC |
| 9 | CC |

Is there anyway to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried LAG() but it only returns the -1 row value.  What I need here is kind of a dynamic number for the offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, last_value(value IGNORE NULLS) over (order by id) as modified_value
from   your_table
;
```